# Problemas con un proyecto android

Tags: android, android-studio

Bueno espero saber explicarme y dar a entender mi problema exactamente.

Estoy iniciando un proyecto para mí localidad y he adquirido en Evanto un script junto con su app.

Con la parte web frontend y backend no tengo ningún problema, el problema lo tengo en la edición, cambios y compilación de la app en android studio, ya que la verdad no tengo mucha idea de cómo convertir ese proyecto en una apk totalmente funcional.

Seguí las instrucciones paso a paso **(o eso creo)** que se me entregarón en la compra pero no consigo que funcione, se que algo no estoy haciendo correctamente por culpa de mi gran ignorancia sobre android.

La cuestión es que ya estoy a punto de tirar la toalla con la aplicación y buscando por internet soluciones os encontré por ello, os pido ayuda en la medida de lo posible para ver la luz y poder acabar el proyecto.

No tendría ningún problema en pasar todo el proyecto lo que quiero es aprender y saber en donde estoy equivocandome.

Muchisimas gracias de antemano.

[image: Captura de mi pantalla con android studio]

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema o error? Prueba a depurar la aplicación, pulsando en la opción **`Run`** del menú superior y luego en `Debug`, o pulsando en la garrapatita de color verde que tendrás siempre visible en el panel superior. Una vez que verifiques que todo está OK podrás generar una App firmada o lo que necesites, eso se hace en la opción **`Build`** y luego `Generate Signed Bundle / APK`

Comment: Muchas gracias lo hice todo pero nada sale muchos errores que no caben en este comentario. El asunto es que no tengo ni idea.

Comment: Puedes copiar toda la traza del error **como texto** y agregarla a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Eres muy amable y te agradezco enormemente tu tiempo ¿Te importaría que te mostrase y enviase el proyecto para que lo veas?

Comment: Lamentablemente no podemos dedicarnos aquí a revisar proyectos enteros, no es el propósito del sitio y sería algo que podría llevar mucho tiempo... Pero si muestras el mensaje de error podremos ayudarte a encontrar dónde está el problema.